# Mongo aggregation String to ISODate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In a collection, I store this kind of document :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55e8a5cba21b9e051eb448d1"),
    "created_at" : "2015-01-01T00:00:24Z",
    ...
}
```

I would like to change the type of created_at from String to ISODate in order to get

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55e8a5cba21b9e051eb448d1"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2015-01-01T00:00:24Z)",
    ...
}
```

I found one solution : iterating through all the collection doing

```
db.trial.find().forEach(
    function(doc) { 
        doc.created_at = ISODate(doc.created_at); 
        db.events_January_watch.save(doc);
    }
);
```

But this is very slow and unefficient, I would prefer to use the aggregation pipeline + $out

This is what I tried :

```
db.trial.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project: {
                created_at : "$created_at",                                     
                created_at_iso: {$add: ISODate("$created_at_noTime") }
            }
        },
        {
            $out: "trialIso"
        }
    ],
    {
        allowDiskUse: true
    }
);
```

Which throws : 
E QUERY    Error: invalid ISO date

I don't understand why since

```
ISODate("2015-01-01T00:00:24Z")
```

works perfectly in the mongo shell.

(Is this because, the $created_at variable is not yet set in the aggregation pipeline ?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do this is using ["Bulk"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) operations

```js
var bulk = db.trial.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0;

db.trial.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
        "$set": { "created_at": ISODate(doc.created_at) }
    })
    count++;
    if (count % 1000 == 0) {
        // Execute per 1000 operations and re-init
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.trial.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
})


if (count % 1000 != 0) 
    bulk.execute();
```